# Pandas separate log file into 2 columns after space and first 4 consecutive numeric values

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with email log files and each row is a log in a pandas dataframe with a field name 'test'.  I am trying to split this column into two columns separating the date from the rest of the log.  Currently I am doing it a sloppy way by separating on the first 6 spaces then joining the date back together.  I would just use `Info:` to separate but sometimes it is a different word.  And I don't want to use 2019 because the year will change.  And in the log file the date has 2 spaces when the day of the week is <10 and one space when it is >=10.  So I would like to split into 2 columns after a space and first 4 consecutive numeric values.   How can I do this more efficiently?

```
df
    test
0   Wed Sep 4 10:32:45 2019 Info: Begin Logfile
1   Wed Sep 4 10:32:45 2019 Info: Version:  ...
2   Wed Sep 4 10:32:45 2019 Info: Time offse...
3   Wed Sep 4 10:32:44 2019 Info: MID 105174...
4   Wed Sep 4 10:32:44 2019 Info: MID 105174...
5   Wed Sep 4 10:32:44 2019 Info: MID 105174...

df = df["test"].str.split(" ", 6, expand = True) 
df['date'] = df[0] + ' ' + df[1] + ' ' + df[2] + ' ' + df[3] + ' ' + df[4] + ' ' + df[5]
df['rest_of_log'] = df[6]
df2 = df[['date','rest_of_log']]

df2
    date                       rest_of_log
0   Wed Sep 4 10:32:45 2019    Info: Begin ...
1   Wed Sep 4 10:32:45 2019    Info: Versio...
2   Wed Sep 4 10:32:45 2019    Info: Time ...
3   Wed Sep 4 10:32:44 2019    Info: MID 1...
4   Wed Sep 4 10:32:44 2019    Info: MID 1...
5   Wed Sep 4 10:32:44 2019    Info: MID 1...
```

Comment: So, your full date format is a consistent width?

Comment: Please update the test data in this question with all possible formats of test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want you can look into regular expressions for this:

```
import re as voodoo

p = voodoo.compile('(.*? [0-9]{4}) (.*)')
m = p.match("Wed Sep 4 10:32:45 2019 Info: Begin Logfile")
print(m.group(1))
print(m.group(2))
```

yields:

```
Wed Sep 4 10:32:45 2019
Info: Begin Logfile
```

in pandas this can be done like this:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({"logtxt": ["Wed Sep 4 10:32:45 2019 Info: Begin Logfile"]})
df["logtxt"].str.extract('^(.*? [0-9]{4}) (.*)$')
```

which yields:

```
    0                       1
0   Wed Sep 4 10:32:45 2019 Info: Begin Logfile
```

Comment: It will fail on such an entry like "Wed Sep 4 10:32:45 2019 Info: MID 1234  etc".

Comment: are you sure? I am testing your example and it works with that.

Comment: Please check my code above (and delete it thereafter). Am I wrong?

Comment: Checked.. agreed there was a problem. Updated regex to be lazy instead of greedy

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply split on "Info:" ?

df = df["test"].str.split("Info:", expand = True)

the full code would be:

```
df["test"] = df["test"].map(lambda x: " ".join(x.split()) #removes double whitespaces
df[["date", "rest_of_log"]] = df["test"].str.split("Info:", n=1, expand = True)
df["rest_of_log"] = 'Info:' + df1['rest_of_log'] #comment from Scott Boston
```

Comment: `df1['rest_of_log'] = 'Info:' + df1['rest_of_log']`  no need for the map.  Just add the string.

Comment: to quote OP: "I would just use Info: to separate but sometimes it is a different word."

Comment: @Scott Boston, Thank you wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @Christian Sloper, oh you are right, thank you for pointing that out. I had overread that. Adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use named groups with regex:

```
df1['test'].str.extract('^(?P<date>\w+\s\w+\s\d{1,2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\d{4})\s(?P<rest_of_log>.*)$')
```

Comment: OP says there is different number of characters depending on day of week

Comment: Explain?  It best if you put all your test cases in your question.

Comment: I am not op, but as far as i understand one testcase is :
"Wed Sep 4 10:32:45 2019" and another is "Wed Sep 14 10:32:45 2019"